# Procedure vs. synthetic method?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I am genuinely confused on the difference between a procedure/flow chart and the synthetic method for a lab report and what exactly a synthetic method includes, and I can't find any information online. I would really appreciate the help if anyone has knowledge about it.

This is what the directions say, but it almost sounds the same as what a procedure would cover.

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: With respect to version 1 of your post: Please type out the text in the image so that it's accessible by search engines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Procedure/flow chart is a short, often diagrammatic, summary of a reaction sequence with reagents, solvents, temperature & yields. It is expected that a competent synthetic chemist would be familiar with the reactions shown and would be able to understand how the product was made.

Synthetic method contains all the details of the reaction. Sources and quantities of reagents and solvents, times and temperatures of reaction, workup and purification procedures, characterisation of product.